# Installing Cocoa Pod dependency without one of it's sub dependency

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

```
pod 'RxGoogleMaps'
```

I am trying to install the above library without one of it's subspecs  `s.dependency 'GoogleMaps', '~> 3'`

This is because due to the nature of our architecture (iOS modular architecture) I had to link `GoogleMaps`  manually (because which is a static library)

Now when I try to install `RxGoogleMaps` , CocoaPods is trying to install `GoogleMaps` as a sub dependency and getting an error since it's already there and linked.

Is there a way to stop this sub dependency from installing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really avoid it being downloaded, but you can strip it from the xcconfig file, to avoid it being linked, by adding a post-install script to your `Podfile`

Something like this:

```
require 'fileutils'

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            if config.base_configuration_reference
                xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
                xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
                new_xcconfig = xcconfig.sub("-framework \"GoogleMaps\"", "")
                File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << new_xcconfig }
            end
        end
    end
end
```